# Unexpected error when publishing photo to page

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I'm trying to publish a photo to a page using the following:

```
FacebookClient client = new DefaultFacebookClient(destinationAccessToken);
BinaryAttachment attachment = BinaryAttachment.with(imageName, imageInputStream);
Photo photoResponse = client.publish("/me/photos", Photo.class, attachment);
```

I'm getting the following response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message":"An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.",
        "type":"OAuthException",
        "code":2
    }
}
```

When I use the same code to publish to a user wall it works fine.

I've also tried posting to `"/{page id}/photos"` with the same result.

The destination access token has the `manage_pages`, `photo_upload`, `publish_actions`, and `publish_stream` permissions amongst others.

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE:**

If I publish to a predetermined album using `"/{album id}/photos"` then it works. Quoting [this Facebook developer blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/):

> `https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/photos` - The photo will be
>   published to an album created for your app. We automatically create an
>   album for your app if it does not already exist. All photos uploaded
>   this way will then be added to this same album.

So is this behavior broken for pages? Or am I misunderstanding something here?

**UPDATE 2:**

I found a [bug report](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/355536551171535) for this issue, so I'm posting that as an answer.

**UPDATE 3:**

The bug seems to have been resolved.

Comment: See [constructor API](http://restfb.com/javadoc/com/restfb/DefaultFacebookClient.html#DefaultFacebookClient%28java.lang.String%29), add a parameter accessToken to the DefaultFacebookClient. Or use a public path (?).

Comment: @JoopEggen - I'm not sure what you mean - can you rephrase? Please post as an answer if it's meant to be.

Comment: `new DefaultFacebookClient(getAccessToken())` but I am afraid you've got none. You will have to await a real answer. It is a session related timeout for allowing access. I am not a genuine facebook programmer.

Comment: @JoopEggen - I've got none what? Are you saying the access token is expired?

Comment: You did not provide one, and hence received an OAuth exception. I wonder why nobody more knowledgeable as I answered yet.

Comment: @JoopEggen - I am providing one: `new DefaultFacebookClient(destinationAccessToken)` where `destinationAccessToken` is the access token for the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the Facebook bug report corresponding to this behavior:

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/355536551171535

So it would seem I'm not doing anything wrong. I guess the temporary workaround would be to check for a predetermined album and create it if necessary, then publish to it. (Note that the `user_photos` permission is not needed for this workaround, since albums/photos on pages are always public).